# Is there a term for removing contractions?

Tags: verbs, contractions, contraction-vs-full-form

Is there an English verb for removing contractions from a body of text?

Like changing "I wasn't there" to "I was not there".

Comment: No, there isn't. _Removing contractions_ is about as terse as one can get.

Comment: The opposite of *contraction* is *expansion*. But beware that removing all contractions in English will make you sound like a Martian.

Comment: Opposite to words contraction, we may think to *disjunction*. But, I am not really sure that it will be understood in that sense.

Comment: I believe this is part of their plan -- once they remove all English contractions, they will conquer us with ease.  I, for one, welcome our new Martian overlords.  Do you not?

Comment: "*Expanding* the contractions" sounds like the best fit to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

By Googling "contraction antonym oxford" [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contract) offered the following:

> **contraction**:   shorten (a word or phrase) by combination or
>   elision.     "these sources were called quasistellar objects, which
>   was soon contracted to quasar"
>   *synonyms:* shorten, abbreviate, cut, reduce, abridge, truncate "the name ‘Jacquenard’ was soon contracted to ‘Jack’ in English"
>   ***antonyms***:   **expand,** **lengthen**

Search for "expand contraction" let to a number of grammar sites giving instructions for dictation; there was also a lead to

*Thomas Middleton and Early Modern Textual Culture*:
By John Lavagnino  p762  (p731 also) expand, expanded, expansion,

> 'later Crane texts expand contractions more than early Crane texts.'

I could find no word to describe the interpretation/ filling out of ***sigla*** which is a similar process, in which the whole page may be transliterated with sigla or in full.